# Linear Algebra - Permutations

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

Is it possible to multiply two permutations of **different** lengths together? If so how would you go about doing it?

Comment: A permutation matrix is a square matrix, and square matrices of different sizes cannot be multiplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what a permutation is intuitively: A bijection from a set of some size, $n$ to itself.

So "multiplication" of two permutation matrices is really just (bijective) function composition. If you have a permutation of $n$ letters, and then apply a second permutation on $n+k$ or $n-k$ for some nonzero $k$, this permutation doesn't know where to send $k$ of the letters in the first case, and is not well defined on the smaller domain in the second case; it would like to send the $n+1, n+2,....n+k$ letters somewhere, but cannot since they are not present in the domain.